# Where can I find high-dimensional (p>n) datasets?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, large-data, high-dimensional

I am looking for "high-dimensional" data for a course project.

The requirements of an ideal dataset for me are:

1.$p>n$ (or at least $p> \sqrt{n}$), where $p$ is the number of variables and $n$ is the number of observations;

2.$p\times n$ is hundreds by hundreds.

I find it's hard to find datasets that meet such conditions so any kinds of topics of the dataset is welcome. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, any genomics application satisfies $p>n$. Just try to google applications in this area,  for instance:

https://rdrr.io/cran/PRIMsrc/man/Real.2-data.html

or in general, at:

https://cancergenome.nih.gov/

Note that you may need to work a bit to get the data in the format you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're into some data pre-processing, natural language databases are good resources. Just to give an example, spam classification using large dictionaries would be just what you seek for. Or, datasets in comp. bio literature, often we might encounter that patient data is scarce and number of attributes might even be larger than number of samples.